# How to notify a user who has been mentioned in a post? (theory)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I have a create post functionality where the post creator can add users to mention on it, i want to use websockets (**i think the best solution)** to notify the every user mentioned in that post.

Which will be the best solution to send this to the client? **I think this approach:**

1. Every socket connected will add it to an array, and then identify it

   socket.to(socketid).emit('hey', 'I just met you');
2. Send every post created to the client and then filter it with the sessionid(nickname) that post has an attribute mentioned in [a,b,c]
3. **Any best solution?**

Im using mongodb and the post collection is structured like this

title,body,mentioned['nickname1','nickname2']

NOTE: I can receive post content on the emit event but how can I notify a specific user mentioned in that post?

Comment: Your approach is fine. I would also consider about the case of offline user , and socket information storing  for scaling.

Comment: I'm using pwa too. But from the server how can I make a logic to know which user has been mentioned and notify it on the client?

Comment: you can have a place to store {userId:{socketId:'asdfasdf','created':datetime}, {socket:{id:user created: datetime}}. Redis should be fine. The above data could be used to  check socketId duplication.

Comment: Yep, that's the approach 1 in the question, but you can imagina how bad will an array with 1 million id? I think that approach its not the best solution. How Twitter or stackoverflow.com send alerts to a specific user?

Comment: store it in redis. if you have 1 million concurrent user u will have 1m open files anyway. getting data from redis is quite fast.

Comment: Are you sure there's no other way to send back the post for mentioned users?. The logic will be, it's there's new post, check if has mentions, if has, then send the post to the mentioned users on the client

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you're trying to give the experience to.

If you want it to be instant, and the user receive the feedback instantly on his screen you can use websockets, or use firebase, which is a real time database. Both would instantly notify the user on his screen.

Comment: I'm using websockets right now, when a user create a post, emit an event to check the database for new mentions, but how can I notify a user that has been mentioned in that post?, from the server how can we know which client has been mentioned?

Comment: you can create a flag for the notification read.
or you can emit a signal/send a request to the server saying that you read or opened that notification, so then the server will know he got notified

Comment: I mean, if I mention you in the post, how can I contact exactly you in the client?

Comment: you need to have identification of your users, and if you have the correlated mentions/notifications with the id of the user you can check whenever the user gets to the page if the userid has mentions not read